# Is $\mathbb{Q}$ a Lie subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

Consider $\mathbb{Q}$ as and additive subgroup of additive Lie group $\mathbb{R}$. Is $\mathbb{Q}$ a Lie subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$? By definition Lie subgroup must be a submanifold, it seems to me that $\mathbb{Q}$ isn't a submanifold (i can't proof this). Why it's important to define a subgroup by a submanifold?

Comment: Lie groups are by definition groups and manifolds, so a sub-thing should also be of the same variety:  a group and a manifold.  (Plus all the required compatibility.)

Comment: If $\mathbb{Q}$ is going to be a manifold, it must be $0$-dimensional.  Does every point of $\mathbb{Q}$ have a relative open set homeomorphic to a point?

Comment: A Lie subgroup is by definition a closed subgroup. So $\mathbb{Q}$ isn't a Lie subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Didier in some texts the topological closedness is not part of the definition of Lie subgroup, but is imposed later by some point-set conditions.  I think it depends on OP's exact definition, but we don't know what that is.

Comment: @Randall the only definition of lie subgroup i have seen is 1)it's subgroup 2)it's submanifold

Comment: Your final question is rather broad and does not fit with the earlier part of your question, but it's at least worth a comment. In general it's not important to define a subgroup by a submanifold. For example, $\mathbb Q$ is, as you say, a subgroup of $\mathbb R$. What's important is to define a **Lie subgroup** as a manifold. This allows you to build a theory of Lie subgroups based on their tangent spaces at the identity, for example.

Answer (score 3):

Correct, this is not a "Lie subgroup".

Take $\mathbb Q$ with the discrete topology, then it is a ($0$-dimensional) Lie group.  And the natural map $j : \mathbb Q \to \mathbb R$ is injective and continuous.  But it is not a "Lie subgroup" because  $j$ does not preserve the (topological, differentiable) structure.

Comment: Is there any differentiable structure on $\mathbb{Q}$? No neighbourhoods in $\mathbb{Q}$ are homeomorphic to some opne subset's of $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Of course there is a differentiable structure: every set with the discrete  topology becomes a zero- dimensional manifold. It just isn't a submanifold og the reals.

Comment: Why are we imposing the discrete topology on $\mathbb{Q}$?  That is not its subspace topology from $\mathbb{R}$.  If we are pondering submanifold-ness, that should be its topology.

Comment: Why does $j$ not preserve the differentiable structure? If $f$ is a differentiable function on $\Bbb R$ the pullback $j^*f$ should be 'differentiable' on $\Bbb Q$ (when we view $\Bbb Q$ as a discrete $0$-dimensional manifold). Or by 'does not preserve ... structure' do you mean it is not isomorphism onto its image (with the subspace structure), so it is an immersed but not regular submanifold?

Comment: The whole point is that the rational numbers can not be turned into a submanifold of the reals, thus they can not be a sub Lie group. GEdgar was just pointing out the ONLY   way the rational numbers can become a real manifold.